# React-Redux : re render child component on mapStateToProps in parent change doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux, and I'm trying to make a component reactive. 
I want to re-render the MoveList component when the prop I'm passing down from parent mapStateToProps changes and it's not working.

I tried giving a key to the movelist component but it didn't work, and Im not sure how else to approach this

Parent component:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        this.loadContact();
        this.loadUser();
    }

    loadContact() {
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.props.loadContactById(id);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
            this.loadContact();
        }
    }

    transferCoins = (amount) => {
        const { contact } = this.props
        console.log('amount', amount);

        this.props.addMove(contact, amount)
        console.log(this.props.user);

    }

    get filteredMoves() {
        const moves = this.props.user.moves
        return moves.filter(move => move.toId === this.props.contact._id)
    }


    render() {
        const { user } = this.props;
        const title = (contact) ? 'Your Moves:' : ''


        if (!user) {
            return <div> <img src={loadingSvg} /></div>;
        }

        return (
            <div className="conact-deatils">
                { <MoveList className="move-list-cmp" title={title} moveList={this.props.user.moves} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user.currUser
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadContactById,
    saveContact,
    addMove
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactDetailsPage);
```

Child component: moveList

```
export const MoveList = (props) => {    
    return (

        <div className="moves-list">
        <div className="title">{props.title}</div>
        <hr/>
            {props.moveList.map(move => {
                return (
                    <ul className="move" key={move._id}>
                        {props.isFullList && <li>Name: {move.to}</li>}
                        <li>Amount: {move.amount}</li>
                    </ul>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the prop you are passing from parent to child is changing? Are you dispatching an action to change the data in redux? Also, can you verify if the data in redux is actually getting changed.

Comment: @KarthickVinod Yes the prop is changing.

Comment: Neither `title` nor `moveList` changes in `MoveList` functional component?

Answer (score 0):

at the end the problem was that the parent component didn't re-render when i called the addMove dispatch. i didn't deep copied the array of moves object, and react don't know it need to re-render the component. i made a JSON.parse(JSON.stringify deep copy and the component.